# Parse Server S3 Adapter Config Issue on Docker

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to enable S3Adapter for ParseServer https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#configuration-options

When I try this:

```
docker run --name parse-mongo-db -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 27017:27017 -d mongo
docker run --name parse-server -e PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=application_id -e PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=master_key -e PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://admin:password@mongo/parse_server?authSource=admin -e PARSE_SERVER_FILES_ADAPTER=./Files/S3Adapter.js -e S3_ACCESS_KEY=XXXX -e S3_SECRET_KEY=XXXX -e S3_BUCKET=XXXX -e S3_REGION=XXXX -e S3_DIRECT_ACCESS=false --link parse-mongo-db:mongo -p 1337:1337 -d parseplatform/parse-server --masterKeyIps "0.0.0.0/0"
```

I start `mongodb` & `parse-server` this way ^^, and I run into this error:

```
docker logs 4e2af6a4d0b8
Error: Cannot find module './Files/S3Adapter.js'
```

Obviously something is messed up in my config. Any leads to get this to work?

Comment: now, if I remove all S3 fields - things come up fine.

Answer (score 1):

The ParseServer docker image doesn’t come with S3 installed, you need to either install it yourself or use an image that already has it. For example, my [parse-hipaa](https://github.com/netreconlab/parse-hipaa) image has it. You can easily create your own docker file and add whatever additional packages you need (you can look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/netreconlab/parse-hipaa/blob/main/parse/Dockerfile) in parse-hipaa for a thorough example:

```bash
FROM parseplatform/parse-server:latest

# Install necessary dependencies as root
USER root
RUN apk --no-cache add git \
 && npm install --omit=dev @parse/s3-files-adapter
USER node
```

Then, your docker command can be the same but change your adapter to point to s3: `PARSE_SERVER_FILES_ADAPTER="@parse/s3-files-adapter"`